# Internet Explorer issue - cant load content

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms, signalr, explorer

I'm designing a web app in asp.net WebForms.

Everything is working OK on all browsers except IE [all versions]

I can load the site and browse it on IE, but eventually, when trying to browse further, IE just can't load content:

message from Fiddler:
1360 Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 13 516 bytes, but client sent 0 bytes.

I can see that IE is trying to download content, but nothing is sent from server.
It eventually ends up in Connection timeout error.

At the same time, the IE instance that causes problem can load up any other website flawlessly

The problem dissapears after closing IE and opening it again, but returns after a while.

Although I don't think that it's a cause of the problem, it maybe important: My app uses signalR.

I ran out of ideas, and that's why I'm asking, because maybe you guys have some directions where to look and what to check.

thanks.

Comment: It is very hard to see w/o seeing the code.